# Display matrix in C

Tags: c

I had searched so much on the forum, but I didn't find a solution for my problem.
How do I print a matrix that is given like this `matrix[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}}` and give it back like:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: A couple of `for`s, the odd `printf` and `\n` will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i,j;
  int x [2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
  for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
      printf(" %d", x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: It was not clear from the question, what was asked for: formatting or inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

This program support not only 2x2 matrix but also `int matrix[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};` or other size.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int matrix[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};

    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(matrix)/sizeof(matrix[0]); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(matrix[i])/sizeof(matrix[i][0]); j++) {
            if (j > 0) putchar(' ');
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple nested for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
   }
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Ha. Just saw this. But you do have a bug though: you need to check `j` in your inner loop ;-)

Comment: You still have two `i++`

Comment: Darn it. I ctrl+c ctrl+v the upper line. note to self: NEVER AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]); // tab-separated. Did you want a space?
   }
   if (i < 2 - 1) printf("\n"); // newline except at the end
}
```

is one way.

Comment: Why do you check the j in the outer loop?

Comment: Rats. I'm going to upvote the question. It's obviously harder than it looks.